# How to encrypt data with aes-cbc for random access use?

Tags: encryption, aes

How can I decrypt a random block of encrypted data using aes-cbc?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks for info, about being off-topic, actually I wanna develop a python module for that using Crypto module, my question can be rewritten replacing gpg and openssl with python's crypto module with some modifications (removing parts about headers), so I guess we can take it easy and consider this as a programming question.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks for following this up, I did so, I can accept it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

First information:

AES has a block size of 128-bits. So when you say "AES-128" the assumption is a key size of 128-bits and "AES-256" the assumption is a key size of 256-bits.

CBC mode requires an iv. The iv is used for the first block, each other block use the value of the previous block in a similar way. See [Cipher Block Chaining (CBC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29).

Decryption must be done on a block boundary. The first block will use the iv, subsequent blocks will use the value of the previous encrypted block essentially for it's iv. Thus decryption can start from other than the beginning of the encrypted data.

An assumption on my part is that gpg and openssl place the iv preceding the encrypted data, that is usual procedure but this is a guess by me but may be more complicated (I am to lazy to look that up). This would explain why decryption from the first block would work and not from other starting locations.

For more information study the available documentation.

There is a good online [AES calculator](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc) provided by Cryptomathic.

Comment: Thanks zaph, I was able to do it in python (decrypt a random chunk of data). I added some text to your answer and accepted it.

Comment: I looked for your edit but could not find it, it must have already been rejected. Adding your own answer was the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

With info in zaph's answer I was able to do it in python like this:

```py
from os import urandom
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import hashlib

IV = urandom(16)
aes = AES.new(hashlib.sha256(b'123').digest(), AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
T='1234567890'*160
C=aes.encrypt(T)

# Now if we make a new aes instance with IV we will be able to decrypt first block:
aes = AES.new(hashlib.sha256(b'123').digest(), AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
aes.decrypt(q[:16]) # It returns b'1234567890123456'

# But if we need to decrypt block 4 we need to instanciate aes with contents of block 3 as iv parameter:
aes = AES.new(hashlib.sha256(b'123').digest(), AES.MODE_CBC, q[48:64])
aes.decrypt(q[64:80]) # It returns b'5678901234567890'
```

So to sum it up if you want to decrypt some encrypted text using aes-cbc from block n to block m for example (which is bytes n×16 to m×16), you need data from block n-1 (bytes (n-1)×16 to (n×16)-1) as IV to start decryption on block n. This way you can decrypt any chunk of data even though you don't have access to whole data except for its first block (first 16 bytes).